# Finding Index of same element multiple times, Java

Tags: java

I have my code here, I enter a full name with three words, and I need to get the initials of the first two words, Like:

Input = Anthony Edward Stark

Output = A.E.Stark

Pls help me

Comment: What does the body of the question have to do with the title? (And what do you mean by "I have my code here"? You haven't shown any code. If you *do* have code, please edit it into the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do the job

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Anthony Edward Stark";
        String names[] = input.split(" ");
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
            if(i< names.length-1){
                result += names[i].charAt(0) +".";
            }else{
                result += names[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```